# MYSql Query - #2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I have a long query with multiple joins that has been timing out. I have already created the `Sponsor_Id` (being used in `WHERE`) in all the sponsor tables as index. The profiler chart shows horrible slowness (75% time in sending data).

---

Here is the query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT masterdetail.eventid) as eventids
FROM   tblsponsor_slave_eventprefrencesdetail userprefrence
       INNER JOIN tblsponsor_slave_sponsor_eventprefrence_category
                  userprefcategory
               ON userprefrence.SponsorId = userprefcategory.SponsorId
       INNER JOIN tblsponsor_slave_sponsor_eventprefrence_locationtarget
                  userpreflocation
               ON userprefrence.SponsorId = userpreflocation.SponsorId
       INNER JOIN tblsponsor_slave_sponsor_eventprefrence_type userprefEventType
               ON userprefrence.SponsorId = userprefEventType.SponsorId
       INNER JOIN tblsponsor_slave_sponsor_eventprefrence_audienceprofile
                  userprefAudiProfile
               ON userprefrence.SponsorId = userprefAudiProfile.SponsorId
       INNER JOIN tblsponsor_slave_sponsor_eventprefrence_industry
                  userprefIndustry
               ON userprefrence.SponsorId = userprefIndustry.SponsorId
       INNER JOIN tblsponsor_slave_eventprefrencesdetail userprefdetail
               ON userprefrence.SponsorId = userprefdetail.SponsorId
       INNER JOIN tblsponsor_slave_sponsor_eventprefrence_audiencetype
                  userprefAudiType
               ON userprefrence.SponsorId = userprefAudiType.SponsorId
       INNER JOIN tblsponsor_slave_eventprefrence_agegroup userprefAgeGroup
               ON userprefrence.SponsorId = userprefAgeGroup.SponsorId
       INNER JOIN tblevent_slave_event_address_city eventcity
               ON userpreflocation.Sponsor_EventPrefrence_LocationTarget =
                  eventcity.Event_Address_City
       INNER JOIN tblevent_slave_event_audienceprofile eventAudiProfile
               ON userprefAudiProfile.Sponsor_EventPrefrence_AudienceProfile =
                  eventAudiProfile.Event_AudienceProfile
       INNER JOIN tblevent_slave_event_industrycatered eventindustry
               ON userprefIndustry.Sponsor_EventPrefrence_Industry =
                  eventindustry.Event_IndustryCatered
       INNER JOIN tblevent_slave_agegroup eventagegroup
               ON userprefAgeGroup.Sponsor_AgeGroup_Type =
                  eventagegroup.Event_AgeGroup_Type
                  AND userprefAgeGroup.IsExist = eventagegroup.IsExist
       INNER JOIN tblevent_master_detail masterdetail
               ON eventcity.EventId = masterdetail.EventId
       INNER JOIN tblevent_slave_others eventothers
               on masterdetail.EventId = eventothers.EventId
                  AND masterdetail.Event_Category =
                      userprefcategory.Sponsor_EventPrefrence_Category
                  AND masterdetail.Event_Type =
                      userprefEventType.Sponsor_EventPrefrence_Type
                  AND eventothers.Event_Gender =
                      userprefdetail.Sponsor_EventPrefrence_Gender
                  AND eventothers.Event_TargetAudience =
                      userprefAudiType.Sponsor_EventPrefrence_AudienceType
                  AND eventothers.Event_Sponsor_Range_Min <
                      userprefrence.Sponsor_EventPrefrence_Range_Max
WHERE  userprefrence.SponsorId = 164
       AND eventagegroup.IsExist = 1
       AND masterdetail.Event_StartDateTime > '2015-08-27'
       AND masterdetail.Event_Category in ( "1", "2", "3", "7",
                                            "9", "10", "11" )
       AND eventcity.Event_Address_City in ( "1", "3", "54" )
       AND masterdetail.Event_Type in ( "2", "3", "4", "5", "7" )
       AND eventindustry.Event_IndustryCatered in ( "13", "18" )
       AND eventAudiProfile.Event_AudienceProfile in ( "1", "2", "10" )
```

Comment: post the explain from your query. i not understand if the query "only" th slow or you lost the connection to the Database

Comment: you can try to change the Value of "max_allowed_packet" in the my.cnf to a higher value to fix it.

Comment: max_allowed_packet may not be the cause...what does your /var/log/messages say?  Is killing Mysql due to OOM? Your buffer/cache settings may need to be adjusted...

Comment: Thanks, i am on a shared hosting and using phpmyadmin. Not sure how to change these variables value.

Comment: Any help with indexing? i doubt my tables are not indexed properly.

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer will (probably) start with the table that is best filtered by stuff in the `WHERE` clause.  Which looks the most selective?  Let's say it is `masterdetail.Event_StartDateTime > '2015-08-27'`.  Then you need an index on `masterdetail` *starting* with `Event_StartDateTime`.

Then it will move on to some other table.  It would probably see:

```
ON eventcity.EventId = masterdetail.EventId
```

implying that `eventcity` is the next table and it needs to get in some how.  It smells like `EventId` is the `PRIMARY KEY`; so no further action is needed.

Then on to the next table.  And the next.  Etc.

These `WHERE` clauses need some discussion:

```
userprefrence.SponsorId = 164
eventagegroup.IsExist = 1
```

They are *column* = *constant*, which makes them very good for indexing.  On the other hand, `IsExist` smells like a true/false flag, which is almost never useful *by itself* in an index.

Anyway, it would *probably* be useful to have a composite index with the field *and* the field that is being `JOINed` on.

Can you justfify a 15-table `JOIN`?  That is a lot.  ("Normalize, but don't over-normalize.")

I'm flying blind -- could you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each (after implementing what you can of my suggestions)?

What I have given you is probably not all that could be done.

`sending data` is useless info; they need to break it down some way.